# ui route - hierarchy prevent innecesary calls to web service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to acomplish the following structure in AngularJs ui route:

- page/operationgroup
- page/operationgroup/:id
- page/operationgroup/operation
- page/operationgroup/operation/:id
- page/operationgroup/operation/route
- page/operationgroup/operation/route/:id

To do this I configured the state like this (reduced for brevity, there is a "seguimiento" root state that i'm not showing):

```
    .state('seguimiento.operationgroup', {
            url: "/operationgroup",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Operation Group' },
            resolve: {
              operationgroup: function($stateParams, OperationGroupService) {
                return OperationGroupService.getOperations();
              }
            },
            views: {
              'body@seguimiento': {
                  templateUrl: "views/seguimiento/common/main.html?d=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
                  controller: "operationgroupController1"
                  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
                },
              'header@seguimiento': {
                  templateUrl: "views/seguimiento/common/headergeneric.html"
                },
              'log@seguimiento': {
                  templateUrl: "views/seguimiento/common/logbar.html",
                  controller: "operationgroupLogController1"
                  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('seguimiento.operationgroup.operation', {
            url: "/operation",
            templateUrl: "views/seguimiento/common/main.html?d=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
            data: { pageTitle: 'Operaciones' },
            resolve: {
              operation: function($stateParams, OperationService) {
                return OperationService.getOperations();
              }
            },
            views: {
              'body@seguimiento': {
                  templateUrl: "views/seguimiento/common/main.html?d=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
                  controller: "operationController1"
                  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
                },
              'header@seguimiento': {
                  templateUrl: "views/seguimiento/common/headergeneric.html"

              },
              'log@seguimiento': {
                  templateUrl: "views/seguimiento/common/logbar.html",
                  controller: "operationLogController1",
                  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
                }
            }
        })
```

In wich OperationService and OperationGroupService both call a web service to fill up the Controller of the views.

The problem I'm experiencing with this is that if I go to the url

page/operationgroup/operation

The "resolve" part of the operationgroup state (parent) also gets called. Wich introduces a massive call for data that I do not need here, because the views only need to use the subset "operation" from OperationService (not the data refered in "operationgroup" from OperationGroupService). 
Same thing happens if I define a controller at the state level (gets called when child url gets hit).

This doesn't happen for the controller views tho. Only the child's state controller being navigated gets hit (ex: body@seguimiento controller). 
So I tough I could just call the service from each view controller, but the following problem arises:
All three views (body@,log@ and @header) need information from the same http.get call to the web service (each view uses a specific part from the info gotten).
So I can't define a call per view because that would cause three calls to the web service instead of only 1.

So my question is: What's the best aproach to build this route hierarchy considering I don't want expensive innecesary calls?

Should I separate all my routes and build something like:

```
.state('seguimiento.operationgroup', {
            url: "/operationgroup", ...

.state('seguimiento.operation', {
            url: "/operationgroup/operation", ...
```

I would like to add that I found the following example on the web of a similar question: [http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/about](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/1/item/a) but this doesn't adress the problem(loads ALL the info of EVERY contact and sub item when you navigate to http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/1/item/a).

Comment: why are you resolving the same operations variable in both routes?

Comment: my bad, i fixed it

Comment: I recommend moving the logic in `seguimiento.operationgroup` to `seguimiento.operationgroup.list` .  Also note that child states  do not need to re-specify views that are specified in the parent states (like you are doing with `header@seguimiento` and `log@seguimiento`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see that i don't have to redefine the header@seguimiento view, but i do have to redefine  log@seguimiento because it uses another controller (if i'm not mistaken). I'm sorry but i don't understand how moving the logic to another state would work. If I create seguimiento.operationgroup and seguimiento.operationgroup.list , would both states have the same URL? Or should I use an empty URL for seguimiento.operationgroup.list ?